# React Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined from constructor/componentDidMount and Unable to set state on unmounted component

Tags: reactjs

At first I had all the state changing functions outside of componentDidMount() and there were no binding issues. But I would get a "cannot change state of unmounted component" or something to that effect, so I put it inside componentDidMount() and am now unable to bind these methods in the constructor.

```
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            portalId: "",
            portalIdError: "",
            password: "",
            passwordError: ""
        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleIdChange = this.handleIdChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.handleIdChange = (e) => {
            this.setState({
                portalId: e.target.value
            })
        }

        this.handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
            this.setState({
                password: e.target.value
            })
        }

        this.handleSubmit = e => {
            const err = this.validate();
            if (!err) {
                fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
                    this.setState({
                        portalId: this.state.portalId,
                        password: this.state.password
                    })
                })
            }
                e.preventDefault();
        }
```

Edit: I've removed the functions to be outside of `componentDidMount` and now have a new problem. I have a `if (authenticated === true) then return <Redirect />` at the top of my render which is what I think is causing the problem. After I `handleSubmit` theoretically it should update the state of the current component `Login` and redirect to the `Home` page. However, after I redirect I am receiving error `Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component.` in the console.

```
handleSubmit = e => {
        const err = this.validate();
        if (!err) {
            fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
                this.setState({
                    portalId: this.state.portalId,
                    password: this.state.password
                })
            })
            if (fakeAuth.isAuthenticated === true) {
                this.setState({
                   redirect: true
                })
            }
        }
            e.preventDefault();
    }

render() {
const { redirect } = this.state;

        if (redirect) {
            return <Redirect to="/home" />
        }
<div className="control">
  <a onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="button is-link">Login</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Those all handlers will go out of the `componentDidMount` function. Current one is wrong. The error you said happened when they were outside due to some other reasons, which needs to be fixed.

Comment: @ArupRakshit When I take them out of the `componentDidMount` I receive error `Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.` After submitting the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not place class methods in lifecycles methods. Put them outside of componentDidMount hook.

The error about you say "cannot change state of unmounted component" usually happens when you component already unmount and then you try update state of component but component is die at this moment.

If you start handling something in `componentDidMount` method, you should unhandling it in `componentWillUnmount` method.

Short example:

```
componentDidMount() {
   something.addEventListener('click', this.handler); //add
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   something.removeEventListener('click', this.handler); //remove
}
```

## Edit

```
fakeAuth.authenticate(() => { .  //this seems to callback, and update state second;
            this.setState({
                portalId: this.state.portalId,
                password: this.state.password . 
            })
        })
        if (fakeAuth.isAuthenticated === true) {
            this.setState({
               redirect: true //// this fires redirect at first
            })
        }
```

Try ty replace this:

```
fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
        this.setState({
            portalId: this.state.portalId,
            password: this.state.password . 
        })
    })
```

with this:

```
fakeAuth.authenticate();
```

I really cant uderstand what is doing:

```
this.setState({
            portalId: this.state.portalId,
            password: this.state.password
        })
```

Comment: I only have one `componentDidMount()` in all of my code so far and it is in another component (the component I redirect to after submitting the form). This contains a fetch request. How do I `componentWillUnmount()` after a fetch request?

Comment: Edit your question please, and share your code, seems your setting your component state after redirect, this is currently wrong.

Comment: I have a `if (authenticated === true) then <Redirect >` at the top of my render for this page. I think this is causing the problem so I moved it into the `handleSubmit` function and have edited my post above to show this. However, now my redirect is not firing.

Comment: Your redirect not firing,  but  this error still present?

Comment: I edited the original post. The redirect is firing now but am still receiving the `cannot change state of unmounted component` error. I think `Login` page is trying to update its state somewhere after the redirect? Let me know if you need more code

Comment: I edit my answer, please see, and try, and write here what happens ok?

Comment: it worked. I overlooked that the ID and password is being set in the onChange already, so no need to set it again after handling the submission. Thank you.